# Quartz-Cron Trigger Syntax : run every minutes from 5:30AM to 4:30PM

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler

In Quartz-Cron, what is the syntax for a trigger to run every minutes from 5:30AM to 4:30PM?

The trigger below will run the job every minutes from 5AM to 4PM. I am not sure how to specify 5:30AM to 4:30PM.

```
<cron-expression>0 0/1 5-16 ? * MON-FRI</cron-expression>
```

Comment: In the past I have used [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to build cron expressions but it seems it can't handle this scenario.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible in Cron... cronmaker is nice. This tool can help too:http://crontranslator.appspot.com/

Comment: Another nice tool is https://crontab.guru/